# WHERE Is Not Null Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using a very complex UNION ALL query to parse out information from an XML import into an existing Access table. I am running into an issue is when I am attempting to write the query to only populate the table if the field is not null. I have tried using an IIF statement at the beginning and I many different iterations various Null statements but all throw errors except this one which doesn't do anything

```
 select SiteVisitCode + '-'  AS Q_SiteVisitCode, IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CC / ' + Station_Name,  IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "CHLPHL-1-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CT / ' + Station_Name,  IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "HOOP-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CH / ' + Station_Name, SiteVisitCode + '-C(A) / ' + Station_Name))),  IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CC ', IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "CHLPHL-1-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CT', IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "HOOP-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CH', SiteVisitCode + '-C(A)'))), 'S-ROUTINE' as Activity_Type, IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE", 'Sediment', IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE-C", 'Sediment','other')), IIF ([COMP]="TRUE", Right([TransectA],Len([TransectA])-InStrRev([TransectA],"/"))+'-C', Right([TransectA],Len([TransectA])-InStrRev([TransectA],"/"))) AS Sample_Collection_Method_ID, '' AS Activity_Comment, 'CLPH' as DEQ_SampleTypeID, 'A' as Activity_Transect, Station_Visit_Date as Activity_Start_Date, Time as Activity_Start_Time
 FROM tblSiteVisit
 WHERE [transectA] is Not Null
 UNION ALL 
 select SiteVisitCode + '-'  AS Q_SiteVisitCode, IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CC / ' + Station_Name,  IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "CHLPHL-1-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CT / ' + Station_Name,  IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "HOOP-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CH / ' + Station_Name, SiteVisitCode + '-C(P) / ' + Station_Name))),  IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CC ', IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "CHLPHL-1-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CT', IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "HOOP-C", SiteVisitCode + '-CH', SiteVisitCode + '-C(P)'))), 'S-ROUTINE' as Activity_Type, IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE", 'Sediment', IIf ([Sample_Collection_Method_ID] = "SED-CORE-C", 'Sediment','other')), IIF ([COMP]="TRUE", Right([TransectP],Len([TransectP])-InStrRev([TransectP],"/"))+'-C', Right([TransectP],Len([TransectP])-InStrRev([TransectP],"/"))) AS Sample_Collection_Method_ID, '' AS Activity_Comment, 'CLPH' as Q_SampleTypeID, 'P' as Activity_Transect, Station_Visit_Date as Activity_Start_Date, Time as Activity_Start_Time
 FROM tblSiteVisit
 WHERE [transectP] is Not Null
 ;
```

In the example below the 2nd entry should not exist as transect P is null:

```
Q_SiteVisitCode|Sample_ID|Activity_ID|Activity_Type|Medium|Activity_Start_Date|Activity_Start_Time|Sample_Collection_Method_ID|Activity_Transect|DEQ_SampleTypeID|Activity_Comment

 test123-|test123-CT / Fish Hatchery|test123-CT|S-ROUTINE|other|12/26/2013|1058|CHLPHL-1-C|A|CLPH   
 test123-|test123-C(P) / Fish Hatchery|test123-C(P)|S-ROUTINE|other|12/26/2013|1058|-C|P|CLPH
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using a CASE statement in your query instead of the IIF?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the way the data is coming in.  It looks like you're selecting from a table in the SQL example.  Is that the problem query?  Is the pipe-delimited data representing that table?

Comment: The import is a XML which imports as a table, this then needs to parse out into other tables. Each of the transects is a column in the table (there are 16 transects) I only want to populate the existing table if there is data in the column for that particular transect. The problem I am having is that I get a return row even when the transect column of the original table is null.

Comment: *"I get a return row even when the transect column of the original table is null."*  Are you absolutely certain transect is Null in that situation?  Could it perhaps contain an empty string ... `Len(transect) = 0`  It is difficult to distinguish between Null and empty string just by looking at a table in Datasheet View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `transectA` is text datatype and you want your query to ignore rows with Null or zero-length strings in that column ...

```sql
WHERE Len([transectA]) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two queries that you're UNIONing together are meant to represent mutually exclusive sets, then you need to indicate that.

In each query you select from the same table, but with a different where clause. In the first query you say where transectA is not null. TrasnectP can still be null here, and those records will be pulled in. Vice versa for the 2nd query.

As others have said - write this as a single query without the union, but use a case statement to check if transecta or tranectp is null and transform that field accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You know that one of your SELECTs are pulling the unwanted record in -- run each seperately to find out which one.  But otherwise, you can explicitly exclude unwanted records like this:

In your first SELECT:

```
WHERE [transectA] NOT IN (null,'') AND [transectP] in (null, '')
```

In your second SELECT:

```
WHERE [transectP] NOT IN (null,'') AND [transectA] in (null,'')
```

---

FWIW -- you might think about using `SWITCH` statements instead of so many nested `IIF`'s -- easier to read & troubleshoot.

Comment: The import is a XML which imports as a table, this then needs to parse out into other tables. Each of the transects is a column in the table (there are 16 transects) I only want to populate the existing table if there is data in the column for that particular transect. The problem I am having is that I get a return row even when the transect column of the original table is null